# How to search for an element in literal array or integer array in cloud search

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I have an cloud search domain where I have index on a column named "color_f_la". Its a faceted index and is a literal array. Sample value for it is :

[
  "Blue",
  "Green"
]

I've been trying to find out the documentation to construct a query which would search for a particular Color, but to no avail. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5):

If you're running the search with the "Structured" Query Parser, you should be able to pass your value directly as if it were a literal. There is no difference for querying literal-array fields.

For example:

```
(and color_f_la:'Blue')
```

Or if you want to return things that have blue or green:

```
(or color_f_la:'Blue' color_f_la:'Green')
```

Or if you want to return things that have both blue and green only:

```
(and color_f_la:'Blue' color_f_la:'Green')
```